# My JSON Deserializetion with HTTPWebRequest return null

Tags: c#, json, json.net

i'm try to deserialize json, the result is work, but when serialize it became null, can you guys tell me where is wrong ?

My Result JSON:

```
    {
    "status": true,
    "hostname": "139.99.32.82",
    "port": 25565,
    "protocol": "tcp",
    "ping": 499,
    "players": {
        "online": 1,
        "max": 1000
    },
    "cached": false
}
```

My Code :

```
    var request = (WebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://use.gameapis.net/mc/query/players/139.99.32.82");
    request.Method = "GET";
    var response = (WebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
    var serverstats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServerStats>(result);
    var players = serverstats.players;
    serveronline.Text = "Online Players: " + players[0].ToString();
```

My Server Class:

```
    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class ServerStats
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public bool status { get; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string hostname { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public List<OnlinePlayer> players { get; }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class OnlinePlayer
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public int online { get;}
    [JsonProperty]
    public int max { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to serialize object `{"online": 1,"max": 1000}` into an array. If JSON you've shown is the right one you need single r/w element as `players`:

```
public class ServerStats
{
    public bool status { get; set;}
    public string hostname { get; set; }
    public OnlinePlayer players { get;set;} // Single item with set.
}

public class OnlinePlayer
{
    public int online { get;set; }
    public int max { get; set; }
}
```

Side note: make sure all necessary property are set-able.